# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML flie line #21: You must supply a layout_height attribute

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have already supplied a layout_value but i still receive this error:

```
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime: Process: pupccb.solutionsresource.com, PID: 15246
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #21: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5949)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6117)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1831)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1743)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.orhanobut.dialogplus.Utils.getView(Utils.java:49)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.orhanobut.dialogplus.DialogPlusBuilder.getFooterView(DialogPlusBuilder.java:276)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.orhanobut.dialogplus.DialogPlus.<init>(DialogPlus.java:111)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.orhanobut.dialogplus.DialogPlusBuilder.create(DialogPlusBuilder.java:265)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at pupccb.solutionsresource.com.util.CreateMaterialDialog.<init>(CreateMaterialDialog.java:50)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at pupccb.solutionsresource.com.activity.TicketDetails.newCommentDialog(TicketDetails.java:248)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at pupccb.solutionsresource.com.activity.TicketDetails.onClick(TicketDetails.java:146)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4455)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18448)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5064)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
03-14 10:47:37.988 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 10:47:39.388 15246-15246/pupccb.solutionsresource.com I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15246 SIG: 9
```

This is the XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/pad_50dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/pad_5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextComment"
                style="@style/editext_graybg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/pad_50dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|top"
                android:hint="@string/comment_details"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:maxLength="255"
                android:padding="@dimen/pad_10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/attachmentLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewAddAttachment"
                    style="@style/button_inner_tab"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/hs_add_attachment_img"
                    android:text="@string/add_attachment" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewCounter"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/character_counter" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llAttachment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <include layout="@layout/fragment_file_attachment" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView> </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the dimens values file:

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>



    <dimen name="step_pager_tab_width">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="step_pager_tab_height">3dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="step_pager_tab_spacing">4dp</dimen>



    <dimen name="pad_5dp">5.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_10dp">10.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_15dp">15.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_20dp">20.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_30dp">30.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_40dp">40.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_100dp">100.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_60dp">60.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_chat_item">45.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="pad_chat_item1">10.0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_7sp">7.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_8sp">8.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_12sp">12.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_13sp">13.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_14sp">14.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_15sp">15.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_16sp">16.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_18sp">18.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="txt_20sp">20.0sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="TEXT_SIZE_MEDIUM">17.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="TEXT_SIZE_SMALL">14.0sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="TEXT_SIZE_SMALL_MEDIUM">16.0sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="note_spacing">4dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="note_content_spacing">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="note_corner_radius">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="note_textsize">14sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="note_title_textsize">24sp</dimen>

    <dimen name="fab_spacing">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_list_spacing">88dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="item_width">192dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="item_height">192dp</dimen>


    <dimen name="toolbar_elevation">4dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="navigation_drawer_width">300dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="top_header_bolder">0dp</dimen>

    <!-- FAB -->
    <dimen name="spacing_large">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="elevation_low">9dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="elevation_high">12dp</dimen>

    <!-- Header -->
    <dimen name="header_height">100dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="header_elevation">5dp</dimen>

    <!-- Header title -->
    <dimen name="title_text_size">25sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="title_left_margin">10dp</dimen>

    <!-- Header image and its background -->
    <dimen name="image_width">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_background_width">68dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_left_margin">26dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_background_left_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_elevation">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="image_background_elevation">8dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_scrollview_size">200dp</dimen>

    <!-- Inner view -->
    <dimen name="inner_padding_top">25dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="inner_padding">16dp</dimen>

    <!-- Primary button -->
    <dimen name="primary_button_width">50dp</dimen>
    <!-- 100 - 50/2 -->
    <dimen name="primary_button_margin_top">75dp</dimen>
    <!-- sqrt(2 * 50^2) -->
    <dimen name="primary_image_width">35dp</dimen>
    <!-- 100 - 35/2 -->
    <dimen name="primary_image_margin_top">82dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="primary_button_margin_right">26dp</dimen>
    <!-- 26 + (50-35)/2 -->
    <dimen name="primary_image_margin_right">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="primary_button_elevation">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="primary_image_elevation">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="primary_button_shadow">77dp</dimen>

    <!-- Secondary button -->
    <dimen name="secondary_button_width">40dp</dimen>
    <!-- 100 - 40/2 -->
    <dimen name="secondary_button_margin_top">80dp</dimen>
    <!-- sqrt(2 * 40^2) -->
    <dimen name="secondary_image_width">29dp</dimen>
    <!-- 100 - 29/2 -->
    <dimen name="secondary_image_margin_top">85dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="secondary_button_margin_right">100dp</dimen>
    <!-- 100 + (40-29)/2 -->
    <dimen name="secondary_image_margin_right">105dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="secondary_button_elevation">10dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="secondary_image_elevation">12dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="secondary_button_shadow">82dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

I have tried changing the layout_height values to "match_parent", "fill_parent", "match_content", @dimens values, and plain dp values. The app stops and this error is returned when that particular fragment with this xml layout is opened.

I have found other answers to similar questions telling to use android:weight and android:weightSum. The problem is there are multiple LinearLayouts within 1 LinearLayout. I do not know if i will distribute the weight among them as well.

It is my first time encountering an error like this. 
Thanks in advance,
Sig

Comment: which particular view does the error occur?

Comment: @CmosBattery lol your comment

Comment: do you have width and height defined in your `@style/button_inner_tab` ?

Comment: All your Views should have width and height defined. Check if, for all cases, you have defined that

Comment: @gj_ I will define the @style/button_inner_tab then check if the same errors occur

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I have defined all of them. Some are defined in the styles they are tagged to

Comment: @gj_ The @style/button_inner_tab has already been defined

Comment: @sigs by "defined" you mean, you have `layout_width` and `layout_height` in that style?

Answer (score 1):

The `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewAddAttachment"
    style="@style/button_inner_tab"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/hs_add_attachment_img"
    android:text="@string/add_attachment" />
```

Is missing its `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

If you'd like it to fill the remaining space of the `LinearLayout` it is contained in, you should add

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

As explained in [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/layouts-attributes-and-you-9e5a4b4fe32c#3730), `layout_weight` allows a View to expand to fill the remaining space after laying out any fixed width/`wrap_content` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error. Line 21 of your layout has the following: `android:layout_height="@dimen/pad_50dp"`.

Your `dimens.xml` does not seem to define `pad_50dp`.